Does requiring people to work massively overtime actually help boost productivity?
I overheard an interesting conversation while in a public place. A woman was talking on the phone, coaching her friend how to be a better manager. Cutting unnecessary details, her point was that people should be assigned tasks in such a way that they have no time margin, indeed, they will have to work overtime so that they don't fall behind on their tasks - because if they do fall behind then consequences will follow. She boasted that in that way she made her team routinely work "till 10 PM and 11 PM". She said that in any other way the company would be "hemorrhaging money on a massive scale", which would be unacceptable. She seemed to be a manager of a white-collar team, giving that an example task was to "create a report", but specific field is unknown to me.
Obviously here we have an elephant in the room, which is about moral considerations of such practices, and another elephant in the room, which is about legal considerations of such practices (I understand she avoids legal issues by not officially requiring working overtime, but rather just setting unrealistic deadlines with the end result being the same). However, for the purposes of this question, I'd like to ignore both.
The line of thought of managers thinking in this way seems to be that their task is to maximize their teams' productivity while minimizing costs. If people work for 12 or 15 hours a day, then more work is done so productivity increases. Perhaps the same work could be done if more people were hired instead, but this would also increase costs. So, from the POV of the company, it is preferable, if not indeed necessary, to make people work as long and as hard as possible while keeping the workforce as small as possible.
Does requiring people to work massively overtime actually help boost performance?
At least in the field of computer programming I have strong doubts: unrealistic deadlines will probably make people commit low quality code that will be a nightmare to maintain later?
Also won't this lead to people being very demotivated and hating their job?
By coincidence I've recently read about W. Edwards Deming, who seemed to be teaching something opposite.
And yet there are very many managers who think precisely just in the way I described above. Citation not needed, I believe, but here is an example nonetheless: Kotak's Nilesh Shah proposes working 12-hour-per-day for 365 days; here's why

VTC - interesting topics, but unfortunately it is prompting discussion and subjection rather than a clear objective answer, so it is off-topic for this website.

Consistent overtime is a sign of inept management. Emergencies happen, but if emergencies are commonplace, then the staffing model is flawed.

"she avoids legal issues by not officially requiring working overtime" that argument doesn't fly in Europe. Employees working (too much) overtime, even unprompted by their manager, is a legal liability for the company.

Some managers measure their own achievement by how often they use their authority on their employees. The idea that a manager is singlehandedly capable of increasing productivity against everyone else's better judgment is an abuse of that authority. Significantly more often than not, managers chase artificial metrics that they've created. Their forced shortcuts and increased pressure on people leads to shoddy work, which leads to more (unnecessary) work down the line. But the manager doesn't have a metric for all the problems their management style caused, so they pretend it's not a problem.

I work almost 12 hours a day as a developer, but from my perspective, it slows down productivity rather than increase. (I get paid well for my overtime so it doesn't bother)

Another factor is how well the team is functioning vs. individual productivity. A well functioning team out produces many more individuals who are not well coordinated. So, the question really is: how is "productivity" measured? When by individual, more time can force more "productivity" while looking at the whole team, better management and better communication builds more productivity.

Quote from a book whose tittle I cannot remember: "You can make people be in the office 80 hours a week. You can't make them work more than 40 hours a week".

Let's remove opinion based: There was a study by Hans Eysenck about productivity in the British arms industry during WWII. You would assume a high degree of motivation. He found that people working 57 hours a week produced less than people working 48 hours a week.

People should simply abandon bad companies so that they fail.

Short Term yes, Long Term Hell No
There are a myriad of factors that play into this:

Do the workers believe in the reason why they have to work longer
Is there a valid reason for this
Are they being compensated for it (both during AND after)
Is there a gratitude and recognition for it.

Let me give a few scenarios:
Company A is working on a new product Launch and in true human fashion, nothing gets done until the last minute. There was a Deadline but due to market reasons it get moved forward by 1 week. The Product is going to be a flagship product and it is all hands-in-deck. The Company asks people to put in OT and pays them Time and a Half for the extra hours.
After launch, there is a company wide meeting by the CEO thanking them all for their hard work - and everyone gets a small additional bonus for getting the product out on time. After this, the Office returns to normal levels of expected overtime.
Company B isnt working on any particularly large project, but they still have more work than they can handle and are understaffed. The Managers insist everyone stay late, none of it is paid, there is no bonus or recognition and eventually staff get burned out and leave, leading to even more understaffing and issues.
So long as the Overtime is goal orientated (We have this reason why we expect extra work), The Goal is valid (The workers believe in the goal), Compensated (either during or after - generally best to be both), is recognized (Thank yous go a long way) and is the Exception rather than the rule - in short bursts it can massively increase productivity.
With Company A - their behavior creates both the incentive to work extra (Bonus + OT pay) and also it creates an expectation that this only happens when it is necessary.


Does requiring people to work massively overtime actually help boost
performance?

There's a difference between boosting performance/productivity and getting more done for free.
Forcing people to work more does not boost productivity. If anything it probably reduces productivity. But forcing people to work more often gets more done - at last in the short term.
Let's say folks that work 40 hours per week can get 1 task completed per hour, and thus 40 tasks per week. Let's say after 40 hours, folks can only complete 0.25 tasks per hour.
Thus overall, forcing workers to work 44 hours gets 1 more task per week completed for each person.
In the long term, too much overtime means your best workers will quit and go elsewhere. You'll be left with lesser workers, perhaps only those who are so bad that they can't be hired elsewhere.

She boasted that in that way she made her team routinely work "till 10 PM and 11 PM".

Most on her team won't put up with that for long. The good ones will leave. The lesser ones will slow down their work.

Not only will your best employees leave you, the ones that stay will be exhausted and not just their productivity per hour will drop, but their productivity per week will. You will get less work done. I think the point where you get nothing in return for overtime is six sixty-hour weeks.

It depends on the work and the reward. When I was in the forestry industry my gang routinely worked sun up to sun down, any weather, 7 days a week for the planting/spraying seasons. We'd be heading out of the hut in the dark, and stopping only when it's too dark to see and head back to the hut in the dark. But we were paid by volume and had a short window to get the trees into the ground and sprayed. Anyone new to the crew who couldn't handle that would be '%#$%ed off'.
As an engineer I have also worked some crazy hours and sustained the effort for a long time. But I made a lot of money.
If the reward isn't as good as you can get elsewhere for the same effort then you will lose your best workers. So you can do this in some locales where jobs are scarce, but in many others you may find it hard to recruit and retain workers.
Some workers thrive on long hours and quality doesn't deteriorate. But others, perhaps the majority, do not. They're physically or mentally, or both, not up to it.

A usual confounding factor with this is the contribution of systems of work.
Usually, such a manager cannot exist in isolation, so a slavedriving attitude tends to imply something about the wider firm or economic environment, and imply something about the normal systems of work in that wider context.
It's relatively plausible for someone to spend all their waking hours on tasks that are sufficiently various and undemanding.
What's not possible is for people to "concentrate" for the entirety of their waking hours, and the harder the concentration the sooner fatigue sets in.
There is a very close analogy with physical activity. People can amble about the house all day every day indefinitely (save for sleep), they can walk several hours (but not every waking hour without rest), and they can sprint for a few minutes (but only for a small part of the day overall).
Usually jobs require concentration because they are characterised by some kind of subtlety and complexity.
If someone is working from say 9AM to 11PM, then you can be assured they are not performing a concentrating job to a normal standard of quality for 14 hours. There is no doubt about the evidence for this, at least.
What may be giving is either that their job isn't a concentrating job, or it's being done badly once fatigued, or the 14 hour span consists largely of rest or diversion.
Usually, the employment of large numbers of people in non-concentrating jobs is nowadays perceived as a major inefficiency and usually considered a fault in job design or the application of machinery and technology.
Work of a bad (or inconsistently good) standard is usually considered to cause hidden costs on the rest of an organisation, such as labour spent by other workers on informal checks, the need to accomodate uncertain quality when making provisions or decisions, and the administration of rework or waste.
And workers who fail to get on with their work can cause an environment and culture of excess chatter, interruption, and where waiting on slow responses prevails, so that even those who are capable of working faster hours become bogged down waiting or participating in diversions.
In each case there's an implied (mal-)adaptation in the system within which work is done, a system which then has an inertia of its own and begins to command long, non-intensive hours when they are neither necessary nor desirable within a more efficient system.
So no, massive overtime never boosts productivity, but it can become something to which an organisation is addicted and descends.
